# How to display website in SWF files

Tags: browser, web, flash

I would like to create a shockwave file that can display a website with an internal webbrowser or something similar. The final target to display the website in a pdf file, but I think the only way to do this, is the swf trick.

I tried to find resources for this on the web, but found nothing.

**UPDATE:**

I am looking for a way to display a website in a downloadable pdf file. The website is only one html file fuelled by jquery and css.

Comment: AFAIK, Flash doesn't have an internal webbrowser, nor it is possible in PDF. Is it an option for you to dinamically generate the PDF? Eg if you use PHP and an appropriate library (tcpdf is in the public domain), it can generate a PDF with dynamic contents coming from the mentioned website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use static websites, but jquery and css transitions are included. How can I pull the content from the website to display it in the pdf?

Comment: PLease update your question: what do you need exactly? To display a static website as a pdf,eg. keeping links between pages etc?

Comment: Yes a static site, but no link required, because it is a one-page website, the navigation is powered by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Download SWF template for your website and edit it in macro media flash editor.

Comment: what kind of SWF template? My site is a HTML site with jquery and css

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PHP script to create a PDF file (my choice for this kind of stuff is [TcPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), which has many example/how to scripts ready to use), and I'd put a captured image of my website in it; there are several websites offering this service for free, just [google it](https://www.google.com/?q=website%20screenshot%20OR%20thumbnail#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=website%20screenshot%20OR%20thumbnail&oq=website%20screenshot%20OR%20thumbnail&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.2591.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0.0..1c..20.psy-ab.PaGFKa96Xeo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bGE,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MzTIAy2H0K0.O&fp=a3e9559978e5d12c&biw=1598&bih=815), for example [webthumbnail.org](http://webthumbnail.org/).

**Disclaimer**: I'm not linked to TcPDF nor Webthumbnail.org in any way, they are just the first examples that came into my mind.